# Xamarin.Forms: Change Android Theme (Especially those buttons)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am working on a xamarin.forms iOS and Android project. 
The standart iOS button (which really is just a blue text) looks so much better than those ugly 
standard Android buttons:

[image]

I know that for instance the Buttons on AppCompat have a better design,
so waht I wanted to do is to simply change the theme in the manifesto:

```
android:theme="@style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light"></application>
```

But this doesnt affect the buttons (or anyything) at all.

What is it I am doing wrong here?

Thank you:)

Best,

J

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Design it's work in both android and iOS

https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library

Comment: Hello. Semms like a good idea, however I have a question: It also wants me to call for this layout in the OnCreate methods in the respective project. But since I am doing almost anything atm in my top project, this activites dont exist yet. What is my best option here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the button style like in iOS, you can just set it `backgroundcolor` to 
`Transparent`

```
<Button Text="this" TextColor="Blue" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked" ></Button>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

If you want to use `XF-Material-Library` plugin. I [update a demo](https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/MyCircleButton.zip), it could running normally. You can compare your application, For the latest version of `XF-Material-Library 1.6.3`, please set target framework to Android 10 like this sceenshot.
[image]

Here is my demo's running sceenshot.

[image]

Comment: @innomotion media Are there any update for this issue?